# MySQL query returning invalid clause error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a query:

```
SELECT 
  f.name as f_name, 
  f.address as f_address, 
  f.business as f_business, 
  f.web as f_web, 
  f.id_service as f_id_service, 
  f.id_city as f_id_city, 
  f.id_firm as f_id_firm, 
  f.phone as f_phone, 
  p.name as p_name 
FROM Firm f 
  left join Price p on p.id_service=f.id_service 
    AND p.id_city=f.id_city AND p.id_firm=f.id_firm 
WHERE 
  p.id_city='73041' AND 
  p.include='1' AND 
  p.blocked='0' AND 
  f.blocked='0'AND 
  p.id_group='44' AND 
  p.id_subgroup='369' 
Group by 
  f.name 
ORDER by 
  f.name ASC
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'Firm.address' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Why do I get this and how can I fix it?

Comment: You get error because column 'Firm.address' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Read and try to understand error messages you get. It is pretty big chance problem is stated there...

Answer (score 2):

You should consider giving your question a better heading..

You can not access columns that's not in your GROUP BY in the select (you may have to put them in an aggregate function like MIN(...) or MAX(...)).

I'm not sure why you have the GROUP BY in your query since you don't do any aggregates?

You may want to remove the GROUP BY all together.
You may want to put all your columns in the GROUP BY.
Or you may want to remove the group by and add a DISTINCT clause after the SELECT in your SQL (removing the GROUP BY will give you one result for each row).

My guess is that you want an SQL like this:

```
SELECT 
    f.name as f_name, 
    f.address as f_address, 
    f.business as f_business, 
    f.web as f_web, 
    f.id_service as f_id_service, 
    f.id_city as f_id_city, 
    f.id_firm as f_id_firm, 
    f.phone as f_phone, 
    p.name as p_name, 
    SUM(p.SOMEKIND_OF_COLUMN) as sumOfPrice
FROM Firm f 
    left join Price p on p.id_service=f.id_service 
        AND p.id_city=f.id_city AND p.id_firm=f.id_firm 
WHERE p.id_city='73041' AND p.include='1' AND p.blocked='0' AND f.blocked='0'
    AND p.id_group='44' AND p.id_subgroup='369' 
Group by 
    f.name, 
    f.address, 
    f.business , 
    f.web, 
    f.id_service , 
    f.id_city , 
    f.id_firm , 
    f.phone , 
    p.name  
ORDER by f.name ASC
```

Comment: a better heading has been given :)

Comment: but i get not dictinct f.name...
please see image with results query http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/66692436.png

Comment: If one of the columns in the GROUP BY have a different value it will get a row of its own. Perhaps you dont want p.name in the group by (and in the select)? Its hard to tell since I really dont know the result you are expecting or the reason your are making the query.